# How to click on information bar in IE browser

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver

[image] 
I want to perform click action on information bar in IE browser using Selnium WebDriver

In fact i want to click on this lin "Pour protéger votre sécurité......" but i can't identify the object

Comment: What do you mean with "information bar"? Is it an element of the page you want to test? Please provide the element markup and the code you tried.

Comment: Using Selenium natively, you cannot. It's outside of Selenium's scope.

Comment: Thanks for response, i add a picture to clarify my question, in fact i'm using IEDriverServer.exe to perform selenium test on IE browser

Comment: This is off-topic, but you can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to click that inside your other tests. But this depends on whether you use java for your tests otherwise can run arbitrary commands on the commandline.

Comment: The use od the IEDriver will not change the fact that Webdriver cannot interact with browser functionality I'm afraid. Webdriver can ONLY interact with members of the DOM, the actual webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to execute mouse movements and clicks with Java native [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29), or libraries like [AutoItX4Java](http://autoitx4java.googlecode.com/hg-history/679df569d514faab6cd423f066358b8f8c32b7c3/dist/javadoc/autoitx4java/AutoItX.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29) and [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to set different internet explorer options before executing script instead of clicking on such information bar as they are not part of your web page. So, you will not get any command in Selenium to handle this. Go to Internet Options, Security tab, and customize particular option level for Internet so that you will not see such information bars. i.e. pop up blockers and all. hope this will help you.